# restoring ipod touch forces update

Tags: ios, upgrade, ipod-touch, restore

I have been trying to restore my 5th Generation Ipod touch from a backup which is stored on my computer. The restore process works fine, however after its' completion there is a white screen lock with a **SLIDE TO UPGRADE** option that prevents me from using the Ipod, unless I upgrade.

Since I do not wish to upgrade the software on the Ipod from the currently installed iOS version (9.2.1), is there some way to circumvent this lockout by Apple?

Comment: No, you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Really ? ! my device is useless on 9.3

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I've asked my own question to be able to answer yours: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232031/what-does-slide-to-upgrade-do

Comment: thanks for elaborating the issue. I am curious to see what answers come of this question.

Comment: I have discovered what happens during the "upgrade." See my answer for a link to a post with more information.

Comment: Did I answer your question well enough? Let me know if I need to add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "slide to upgrade" screen doesn't update your iOS firmware; [it simply prepares your backup for iOS 9](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/232031/18387).